# What is the problem with the following python socket server code?

Tags: python, sockets, server, serversocket

Why is it that the following server code cannot seem to accept new connections with clients even after the first connection is closed?

```
def bindPort(port):
    global return_response
    serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        serverSocket.bind(('', port))
    except:
        print("Cannot bind to port. Error: " + str(sys.exc_info))

    serverSocket.listen(2)
    print("The server is ready to receive")
    count = 0
    while True:
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        count += 1
        print("Accepted {} connections so far.".format(count))
        print('Connection established from {}'.format(addr))
        while True:
            sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            if not sentence:
                print("Empty")
                break
            print(sentence)
            #parseIncomingRequest(sentence.decode())
            print(return_response)
            connectionSocket.send(return_response.encode())
            return_response = ''
        print("Closing loop")
        connectionSocket.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

I apologize for not reading the question properly

1)declare the return response variable before you use it

2)break out of the second while loop if you want accept an other connection .In the question you said that no connections were being accepted after the socket was closed but for the socket to close you have to break out out of the second while loop.or in my opinion you should remove the second loop .

3)if you want to keep listening on the socket and still be able to receive other connections use the threading module

```
def bindPort(port):
  global return_response
  serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  try:
    serverSocket.bind(('', port))
  except:
    print("Cannot bind to port. Error: " + str(sys.exc_info))

  serverSocket.listen(2)
  print("The server is ready to receive")
  count = 0
  while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    count += 1
    print("Accepted {} connections so far.".format(count))
    print('Connection established from {}'.format(addr))
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)    
    if not sentence:
          print("Empty")
          break
    print(sentence)
     #parseIncomingRequest(sentence.decode())
    return_response = ''
    print(return_response)
    connectionSocket.send(return_response.encode())
    connectionSocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    connectionSocket.close()
```

4)or if you want to keep the loop for further modfication

```
import socket

def bindPort(port):
  global return_response
  serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  try:
    serverSocket.bind(('', port))
  except:
    print("Cannot bind to port. Error: " + str(sys.exc_info))

  serverSocket.listen(2)
  print("The server is ready to receive")
  count = 0
  while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    count += 1
    print("Accepted {} connections so far.".format(count))
    print('Connection established from {}'.format(addr))
    while True:

        sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        if not sentence:
            print("Empty")
            break
        print(sentence)
        #parseIncomingRequest(sentence.decode())
        return_response = 'a'
        print(return_response)
        connectionSocket.send(return_response.encode())
        break

    print("Closing loop")
    connectionSocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    connectionSocket.close()
```